# How to use CDI @ConversationScope in memory efficient way

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, conversation-scope

Currently I am experimenting with CDI @ConversationScoped beans following the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/).

While monitoring memory usage, I found for a bean with two collections of 800+ Objects and other few objects its taking more than 60MB session space.

I am aware, it has to maintain the whole view state and changes in conversational context, but taking this huge amount of memory really surprises me.

Is there anything I might be missing or any way to make the bean more memory efficient.

Comment: *"a bean with two collections of 800+ Objects"* is in first place wrong. CDI can't do much against such an implementation. You'd better take a step back and look at e.g. pagination/filtering, JPA L2 cache, etc.

Comment: Wow, comment from BalusC, really a lucky day for me.

I am looking into pagination/filtering. Had a little prior working knowledge of JPA L2 cache

Comment: Bean should hold only the data which is absolutely necessary to present to the enduser. E.g. if you're presenting it in a (paginated) HTML table, then simply load and hold only the records for the current page in bean. Usually it are only 10, 25 or 50.

Comment: Currently after fetching the list  i am presenting it using primefaces   datatable. Holding only records of requested page is a good idea, looking into implementation details.

Comment: PrimeFaces? That's even more easy. It supports `LazyDataModel` out the box: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml Inside the overriden `load()` method, just load *exactly* the records based on offset/limit/sorting/filtering provided via `load()` arguments. Noted should be that their example is kind of confusing because a "static" `List` is used for demonstration purposes (i.e. not DB based) which they then `sublist()`, but you should ignore that part.

Comment: ```LazyDataModel```, really interesting. That solves the large collection problem nicely. Thanks a lot :) Started working on it

Comment: Which of those is most helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13972193 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/5548587?

Comment: Went through both, got the main idea, should do range query instead of subList approach.

Many thanks :)