# JSF Primefaces Pagination with Backend

Tags: jsf, primefaces, pagination

Maybe it's a bit weird, but I don't know how to get the pagination of PrimeFaces to my backend. I know there is the showcase and there are multiple answers here but I'm questioning if it really has to be like this.
Additionally my project is not structured with DAO and things, which leaves me in the dark.

I use a Spring Boot config. The grounding of the whole project is that tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot

But now it's much bigger, has a real database and such things. I already implemented a search where I use Specifications to find objects. There I can also give the search a pageable object.

In my head I thought I can do a pageable object for the normal showing datatable and somehow connect it to the buttons of Primefaces.

Because I load my data right in the controller of the view with

```
public void loadData() {
        eintraege = telefonbuchRepository.findAll();
}
```

So I don't know how to use the lazy loading process in here. Please also teach me if I'm wrong and somewhere else are already answers for this.

Comment: showcase already have lazy loading for datatable. 
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

Comment: @ZawThanoo I already told you I know this. This doesn't help me a bit how to implement it, when I have no DAO class

Comment: Get pagination index and size of datatable in your 'loadData' method. and change your `findAll` method using `limit` and `offset` for pagination. You might need to change query ..example `SELECT * FROM  telefon WHERE ..... LIMIT 20 OFFSET 2`

Comment: use `LazyDataModel` in datatable

Comment: @ZawThanoo the possible duplicate is near that. I don't understand what is getJpaController() in this example. I just need to get the pageNumber and pageSize somehow and then it would work. Because I can use telefonbuchRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize)).getContent() but I don't know hot to get the values

Comment: Here `LazyDataModel` example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548587/primefaces-datatable-jpa-hibernate-pagination

Comment: @ZawThanoo sorry like I already said. I try to catch the example but I don't understand it. What is getJpaController() and this things? It looks uncomfortable and not necessary for me when I only need to have two integer values

Comment: @ZawThanoo ok I implemented it right like in the possible duplicate answer. It literally works, but if I skip a page nothing loads. And I don't know why. On the first page everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. So I just implemented LazyDataModel

```
public class TelefonbuchListController extends LazyDataModel<Telefonbuch> {

    private LazyDataModel<Telefonbuch> lazyModel;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int pageSize = 5;

    public void loadData() {
        lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<Telefonbuch>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public List<Telefonbuch> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
                    Map<String, Object> filters) {

                List<Telefonbuch> result = new ArrayList<Telefonbuch>();

                if (first == 0) {
                    result = telefonbuchRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(first, pageSize)).getContent();
                } else {
                    first = first / pageSize;
                    result = telefonbuchRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(first, pageSize)).getContent();
                }

                return result;
            }
        };

        lazyModel.setRowCount((int) telefonbuchRepository.count());
        lazyModel.setPageSize(pageSize);
    }
```

You should pick the int pageSize like one number of your rowsPerPageTemplate. Because I'm working with the JpaRepository I wanted to use the chance of Specifications and Pageable objects. The form of a Pageable object is `PageRequest.of(int page, int size)`

So I needed to get the pagenumber instead of the first of this page. Just a simple if statement helped me to decide if it's the first page or not. I get the pagenumber with `first / pageSize`.

Don't forget the getter and setter for `LazyDataModel` and `pageSize`.

My .xhtml datatable looks like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="telefonbuch" lazy="true" widgetVar="tableWv" value="#{telefonbuchList.lazyModel}" style="margin-bottom:20px" paginator="true" rows="#{telefonbuchList.pageSize}" dynamic="true" 
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,8,10">
```