# p:datatable lazy pagination: after click on paging "first" became equals to page size

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My JSF bean with lazy data model

```
private Integer pageSize = 15;

private Integer first = 0;


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    responseDataList = new ResponseDataList();
    responseDataList.setPageSize(pageSize);      
}

public class ResponseDataList extends LazyDataModel<User> {

    public int total = 0;
    public int dataSize = 0;

    @Override
    public List<User> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        List<User> data = new ArrayList<>();
        try {


            total = userRestClient.getTotalCount().intValue();


            int count = (first + pageSize);
           data = userRestClient.findAllUsers(first, count).getUserList();

            dataSize = data.size();


        } catch (Exception es) {

        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public User getRowData(String rowKey) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(User object) {
        return object.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return (int) total;
    }
}
```

My data table:

```
        <p:dataTable var="list" id="userTbl"
                             value="#{usersBean.responseDataList}"
                             paginator="true" rows="#{usersBean.pageSize}" first="#{usersBean.first}"  reflow="true" 
                             paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} 
                             {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" 
                             lazy="true"  rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                             >
```

When I click to pagination first time "first" is zero, the second time is 15. Whats why paging is crashed. total is the whole data count in database.

I do not understand how is growing "first" and where is my mistake?

Comment: There is no mistake. `first` is the value where you in your database should start searching (to be used in a 'limit'). If you'd go to page 3, it should be 30 in your case and 45 and 60 etc. And what is the 'crashing' ? And what is your PF version?

Comment: My version of primefaces is 7

Comment: I think offset calculation is wrong, for second page backend receive start: 30, it means it is find 30-rd page which does not exist

Comment: After clicking on the second page but backend receive start as 15, but I have only 13 pages...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF Primefaces Pagination with Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749675/jsf-primefaces-pagination-with-backend)

Answer (score 0):

After reading 
[JSF Primefaces Pagination with Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749675/jsf-primefaces-pagination-with-backend)
I found out that PrimeFaces passes the number of the first record while I was suspecting it to be the page to start on which is what is used in our service. So dividing the PrimeFaces first by the page size and passing the result to our method like shown in the code below made it work.

```
if (first == 0) {
    data = userRestClient.findAllUsers(first, pageSize).getUserList();
} else {
    first = first / pageSize;
    data = userRestClient.findAllUsers(first, pageSize).getUserList();
}
```